# How to work around Unrecognized image loader: null in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

My application, written in Java 8 using JavaFX, takes screenshots, or rather, snapshots, and twice it generated this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized image loader: null
    at javafx.scene.image.WritableImage.loadTkImage(WritableImage.java:240)
    at javafx.scene.image.WritableImage.access$000(WritableImage.java:46)
    at javafx.scene.image.WritableImage$1.loadTkImage(WritableImage.java:51)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doSnapshot(Scene.java:1236)
    at javafx.scene.Node.doSnapshot(Node.java:1864)
    at javafx.scene.Node.snapshot(Node.java:1942)
```

So far, in my application, I wasn't able to reproduce it. Searching for this issue I found this:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8116783

that points to:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8088198

It seems to be an open bug in JavaFX: "Exception thrown from snapshot if dimensions are larger than max texture size".

The description of the bug says that it happens occasionally. Does anybody know if catching the exception and retrying would be a good way or workaround it?

**Update**: when I tried to reproduce this error by making the screenshot very big, I got a completely different error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderContext.initLCDBuffer(BaseShaderContext.java:703)
    at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderContext.validateLCDBuffer(BaseShaderContext.java:725)
    at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.initLCDSampleRT(BaseShaderGraphics.java:1925)
    at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.drawString(BaseShaderGraphics.java:2059)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext$10.doPaint(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:936)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext$Composite.paint(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:1500)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext$Composite.paint(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:1485)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.drawString(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:948)
    at com.sun.webkit.graphics.GraphicsDecoder.decode(GraphicsDecoder.java:299)
    at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCRenderQueue.decode(WCRenderQueue.java:92)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.paint2GC(WebPage.java:734)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.paint(WebPage.java:701)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.web.NGWebView.renderContent(NGWebView.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$5.draw(QuantumToolkit.java:1393)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$5.run(QuantumToolkit.java:1429)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It similarly is a thread with no call touching my code at all.

Comment: My assumption would be that re-trying will never work, as the texture size probably corresponds to some hardware resource (probably directly related to VRAM).  If possible, perhaps limit the maximum size of the scene when taking the snapshot, or take snapshots of parts of the scene?

Comment: I can't limit the size of the scene. Taking it in parts might be doable. I need to look at the snapshot API. Without being able to reproduce the bug though, I don't know if that's a solution.

Comment: The bug report you linked suggest scaling can affect it... Maybe try bringing up the scale until you can reproduce it on  your system?

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me too...

This happens if the snapshot ends up being to big.

I was able to fix this by adding a scale in `SnapshotParameters` to say, half. Once you lay your hand on the image, you can do just anything you want, including getting it back to size.

Comment: Just to be clear, this would cause the screenshot to be at a lower resolution. Correct?

Comment: Not really sure about this as I had a little different situation.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue by having a big snapshot.

Comment: Adding a large scale, like 10 should trigger it.

Comment: I added some information to the question, when I do that, I trigger a different exception.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:**

- even if using Oracle JVM, see: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=20415996
- use `-Dprism.poolstats=true -Dprism.verbose=true` to check your maxvram limit and to see how much vram you actually consume
- setting `-Dprism.maxvram=xxxxM` to lower value might help to reproduce the problem
- setting `-Dprism.maxvram=xxxxM` to higher value might help to solve the problem

---

**my case (for anyone interested)**

As suggested in the link above I used `-Dprism.poolstats=true -Dprism.verbose=true` and found that maxvram is high enough. Anyway, to be really sure, I added `-Dprism.maxvram=1024M -Dprism.targetvram=512M` but it didn't help. There was enough memory but the allocation kept failing with the following errors:

```
D3D Vram Pool: 66.929.834 used (12,5%), 81.273.002 target (15,1%), 536.870.912 max
36 total resources being managed
average resource age is 12,6 frames
0 resources at maximum supported age (0,0%)
5 resources marked permanent (13,9%)
0 resources have had mismatched locks (0,0%)
0 resources locked (0,0%)
31 resources contain interesting data (86,1%)
0 resources disappeared (0,0%)

Growing pool D3D Vram Pool target to 116.658.814
Growing pool D3D Vram Pool target to 131.338.878
Growing pool D3D Vram Pool target to 159.043.730
D3D hresult failed :D3D_ERROR ffffffff8007000e
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
        at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DContext.validate(D3DContext.java:133)
        at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DContext.validatePresent(D3DContext.java:183)
        at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DRTTexture.readPixels(D3DRTTexture.java:116)
        at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DRTTexture.readPixels(D3DRTTexture.java:90)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$5.run(QuantumToolkit.java:1437)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
D3D Vram Pool: 109.314.750 used (20,4%), 159.043.730 target (29,6%), 536.870.912 max
37 total resources being managed
average resource age is 13,1 frames
0 resources at maximum supported age (0,0%)
5 resources marked permanent (13,5%)
0 resources have had mismatched locks (0,0%)
0 resources locked (0,0%)
32 resources contain interesting data (86,5%)
0 resources disappeared (0,0%)

2018-07-17 18:05:09 [JavaFX Application Thread] de.apris3.client.ErrorHandler.handle()
   ERROR: : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized image loader: null
        at javafx.scene.image.WritableImage.loadTkImage(WritableImage.java:240)
        at javafx.scene.image.WritableImage.access$000(WritableImage.java:46)
        at javafx.scene.image.WritableImage$1.loadTkImage(WritableImage.java:51)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.doSnapshot(Scene.java:1236)
        at javafx.scene.Node.doSnapshot(Node.java:1864)
        at javafx.scene.Node.snapshot(Node.java:1942)
        ...
D3D Vram Pool: 112.230.142 used (20,9%), 159.043.730 target (29,6%), 536.870.912 max
40 total resources being managed
average resource age is 13,0 frames
0 resources at maximum supported age (0,0%)
5 resources marked permanent (12,5%)
0 resources have had mismatched locks (0,0%)
0 resources locked (0,0%)
35 resources contain interesting data (87,5%)
0 resources disappeared (0,0%)
```

Obviously, JVM couldn't allocate enough memory even though the limit was high enough. Searching for `D3D hresult failed :D3D_ERROR ffffffff8007000e` revealed it's actually a Windows error (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/common-hresult-values):

```
E_OUTOFMEMORY   Failed to allocate necessary memory     0x8007000E
```

Finally, after checking the device manager, it turned out that the client had installed a new graphic card and Windows Updated screwed the drivers up.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem when trying to make a snapshot from a large node.
In my case scaling was not a possibility since I needed a high resolution image.
To solve the problem I made multiple snapshots from subsections of the node and stiched them together afterwards.

Here is the function I wrote:

```
private void exportPng(final Node node, final String filePath) {

    final int w = (int) node.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
    final int h = (int) node.getLayoutBounds().getHeight();
    final WritableImage full = new WritableImage(w, h);

    // defines the number of tiles to export (use higher value for bigger resolution)
    final int size = 2; 
    final int tileWidth = w / size;
    final int tileHeight = h / size;

    System.out.println("Exporting node (building " + (size * size) + " tiles)");

    try {
        for (int col = 0; col < size; ++col) {
            for (int row = 0; row < size; ++row) {

                final int x = row * tileWidth;
                final int y = col * tileHeight;
                final SnapshotParameters params = new SnapshotParameters();
                params.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(x, y, tileWidth, tileHeight));   

                final CompletableFuture<Image> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

                // keeps fx application thread unblocked
                Platform.runLater(() -> future.complete(node.snapshot(params, null)));
                full.getPixelWriter().setPixels(x, y, tileWidth, tileHeight, future.get().getPixelReader(), 0, 0);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Exporting node (saving to file)");

        ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(full, null), "png", new File(filePath));

        System.out.println("Exporting node (finished)");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this with a 7000x3000 pane, which erroneously contained a node with an x-coordinate of 43,000 (supposed to be 4,300).

I didn't see the node of course, but it resulted in this error when trying to take a snapshot; removing it fixed the issue.